# Javascript Date Object returning incorrect first day of the month

Tags: javascript, date

I'm using the following code in a React app to get the first day of the month (to set defaults for a date picker component).

```
let date = new Date();
let firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

For some reason today, on 1st April, it's returning 31st March. I've tested in Chrome console  and various other online JS runtime tools and some return 31-03-2022 and some return 01-04-2022. Is there something I'm missing?

Edit:

My main issue was I needed a YYYY-MM-DD format in the user's local time zone. Using `.toISOString` provides UTC time zone and I'm unable to find a solution which circumvents this. I'm using the following workaround (helped by Mac's answer):

```
 let date = new Date();
 let firstDayCopy = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + date.getFullYear();
 let firstDay = firstDayCopy.split("-").reverse().join("-");
```

Edit 2:

Or of course, just reverse the order to get:

```
let firstDay = String(date.getFullYear() + '-' + String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0'))
```

Comment: ["The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z""](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let date = new Date();
let firstDay = date.getDate() + '-'
 + (date.getMonth()+ 1) + '-' + date.getFullYear();
```

or this, if You want to have the result format with '0':

```
let date = new Date();
let firstDay = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0') + '-'
 + String(date.getMonth()+ 1).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + date.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

As robertklep stated, timezone plays a large roll in dates.

The problem with your result is being masked by the fact you are slicing the date part of the ISOString. You'll likely see the full string as:

"2022-03-31T23:00:00.000Z".

Notice the time is 1 hour earlier than local time? This is in line with UTC.
and is due to my current timezone that is offset by 1 hour.

If you're not concerned about timezone, simply use: .toLocaleDateString();

```js
let date = new Date();
let firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
console.log("ISO-8601", firstDay.toISOString());
console.log("Local String:", firstDay.toLocaleDateString("en-GB"));
```

you can also use .toLocaleDateString("en-US") depending on format

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clarifying what the problem was. Because my time zone (GMT) was identical to UCT until recently, the issue never presented itself! However I specifically need a YYYY-MM-DD format for the date picker, and localeDateString unfortunately doesn't work for this